# Android button on top of image not working

Tags: android, button, layout, imageview, scrollview

The layout is: On top of the view display image and on top of the image, in the top-right corner display position-persistent button (while scrolling down for the text below the image-the position is fixed). It's not working: The button hides under the image, and only when I scroll down to the white background of the text, I can see the button. Here is the code. The button is custom shape: Oval colored with image as background. I also tried to change android:**background**="@drawable/btn1_shape" to android:**src**="@drawable/btn1_shape" and it's not worked either. I'm talking about **pre** matheirial theme design (with it`s Z value etc.) because I need to support backward compatibility...

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn1_shape" />

    <ScrollView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/picture1" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>

//Button shape xml: @drawable/btn1_shape
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/primary"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/picture2"/>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should declare the button after you declare your scrollview if you'd like the button to appear on top. So just change places between the button and the scrollview. If I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 2):

what i understand , your problem is solved by,

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.MainActivity" >


<ScrollView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/picture1" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/btn1_shape" />
</RelativeLayout>
```